# Problem with UIScrollView inside another UIView

Tags: iphone, cocoa, touch

I have this UIScrollView inside another UIView, not occuping the entire area (all this is initialized via nib file). I added some content to the scroll view, but whenever I scroll it, the UIScrollView content area moves outside the ScrollView frame, over the UIView area not designated for displaying it.

Shouldn't it remain inside its frame even when I scroll it?

Comment: Can you post your code on the frame sizes you set for the various views involved?

Comment: As I said, I have initialized the views by a nib, so I haven't explicitly set the frames. I have only modified the content size of the UIScroll view to fit its content using the apposite method [UIScrollView setContentSize].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be that the `clipsToBounds` property of your UIScrollView is set to NO. Check the setting in IB, or you can set it in code like so:

```
scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Failing that, double check that your UIScrollView has exactly the bounds you think it does. Is there any autoresizing flag stuff going on that might be changing the scroll view's bounds?

Answer (score 0):

try to set the clipsToBounds to YES, it may be that:

```
yourViewController.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

if not... fbreto is right, post your code...

Comment: yes, I eventually had this property set to no. Thank you and occulus for saving me much time!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have setContentSize. And also set the frame size of the uiviews  inside the uiscrollview correctly when you add them.

Here is a sample code of it http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Scrolling/Introduction/Intro.html